# Cannot access any element inside frame using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, user-interaction

In short, I am trying to press the "NEXT" button in this image. Its corresponding HTML is highlighted in the Elements tab on the right. It's a button. However, the entire frame is somehow not searchable easily. I tried pressing it in many ways such as:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.page_btn_font.btnNextNormal.ng-binding').click()
```

I tried a lot more but nothing worked. So I went to [one of the suggested questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061765/how-to-access-frame-with-python-selenium) when I tried posting this question and tried to list all the buttons in the page. Surprisingly, I only found, and could click, the two buttons in the upper header on the right: **Tools** and **JOHN DOE**. In short, I cannot even access the frame below with all the buttons.

I have checked the top of the HTML code and also posted a snippet of it below the main picture. The entire frame is highlighted when I hover over the second div with id='content-container" so I somehow have to get into that. Keep in mind the button itself is 10-15 layers deep into divs so going in order will not be easy if we go that route.

Please see the picture at full zoom.

[image]

Comment: Adding the html code as image is bad practice and no one will write that for you. Add the html code as part of post not as image. Pleaase read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.If the URL of this page is public share that.

Comment: Is it in an iframe and what site is it?

Comment: @zack fair Please share url to double check and give solution to this ?

Comment: @Dev I added the code as a picture in this case because I think the problem is not really in the part I showed. That's the button I want to click. But the problem is bigger than that. it's how to access this frame at all, for which I provided a higher-level view of 5-6 lines at the end. I could post the entire code but it would be a lot. And I'd have to remove whatever personal information there is, which would also take a while.

arundeepchohan How do I know it's an iframe? It's an Everfi training module. So not a public link unfortunately.

JustinLambert Not public URL :(

Comment: Do you think _`I think the problem is not really in the part I showed. That's the button I want to click. But the problem is bigger than that`_ this really makes sense

Comment: Yes. The problem is not in the part of the code on the right, not in the little details of the frame itself. I know which button to click and I can find it in many ways. But the problem is I cannot access this frame (and most of the right-hand side code) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following xpath to click the next button

```
//button[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

Comment: This returns an empty variable as I mentioned. This is the key problem. I am not able to access anything inside the frame.

Comment: can you sahre url here to check ?